# What is the alignment of a Gold Shadow Dragon?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, alignment, dragons

What alignment are Gold Shadow Dragons? I recently purchased a miniature booster box and inside I found a Gold Shadow Dragon and have not been able to find any sources that describe its alignment. Since I am new to 5th edition I am unsure of the rules regarding creatures with the shadow subtype.

Answer (score 31):

A Shadow Dragon is the same as the regular version of the dragon, but with the changes detailed under “Shadow Dragon Template” on page 84 of the *Monster Manual* applied to it. The template does not change alignment, so the alignment of a Gold Shadow Dragon is the same as that of a regular Gold Dragon.

Answer (score 3):

You're the GM. It's any alignment you want it to be. I've created a Gold Shadow dragon who is LE. The millenia spent in the shadow realm has corrupted his morality. He now sees all life as to chaotic to endure and its his duty to end it all. To that end he is pursuing a path to godhood with the final plan of killing all other gods and laying waste to the multiverse.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.